# That is so strange ,WHY

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ascii

It is so strange!!!The first command work well ,but the second output error.forgive my poor english

```
 1.printf '%d\n' "'a"
 2.printf '%d\n' "a"
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: The 97 is a clue. It would appear to be treating `'a` as though it were `'a'` -- a C character literal. 97 is the character code for `a` in ASCII and basically all other non-obsolete character encodings. That's some pretty permissive parsing. :-)

Comment: No, it's treating `'a` as a two-character string. It has nothing to do with shell parsing. The double quotes are ensuring that the `'` *is* treated literally, as `printf` itself makes use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the bash man page, (in the pretty lengthy section titled *SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS*) about command `printf`:

> Arguments  to non-string format specifiers are treated as C constants, except that a leading plus or minus sign is allowed, and **if the leading character is a  single  or double quote**, the **value is the ASCII value of the following character**.

So you would also have succeeded with

```
printf '%d\n' \"a
```

Comment: (Apologies for the edit, I didn't read the quote carefully. I was always under the impression that it was only the single quote that `printf` used for getting the ASCII value of the argument.)